# iphone gps accuracy, can it trigger an event based on location?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, gps

I have an issue that i am having trouble to solve. We are about to develop an iphone locative  application that would take you around the city with audio that would be played based on the location. I was wondering, do you know how accurate the iphone GPS will be? In terms of actual distance. I am reading 250 m on line but it looks a lot. Plus the gps in the iphone finds my location more precisley than 250 m. I know it is a generic question, but mabe you guys can give me a feedback about it, i am quite desperate and exausted. what we would live to do is, every 70-80 m, put a pin on a map with an audio file, when the user crossed the pin it would trigger an event that is the audio file. I just would love to know how accurate the gps could be so that i can start designing the experience. 
Thanks a lot

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution to fire a event when app is in background?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've seen iPhone's GPS as accurate as 3m (at least that's what it said on my device when testing).

There is also a [new API](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CLLocationManager/startMonitoringForRegion%3adesiredAccuracy%3a) since iOS 4.0 that you might be interested in that will enable you to set a region for the device to monitor and it will automatically generate a callback when the user crosses the virtual fenceline depending on how accurate you need that to be.  This is particularly useful when the app is sent to the background since you can simply monitor the user's location using `CLLocation` when the app is in the foreground:

`- (void)startMonitoringForRegion:(CLRegion *)region desiredAccuracy:(CLLocationAccuracy)accuracy`

Comment: OMG. you just solved it for me. so basically what you are saying is, i can set up a region where i want my trigger to happen and can be precise like 3 m? i mean, i dont need it to be so precise, but potentially i draw a virtual fence on the map and when the user crosses it, a callback happens? By callback you mean a designed action? Thank you so much, this is pure gold

Comment: It's exactly like a virtual fence. I'm. It sure about the specifics of the callback as I've never used it. Take a look at the docs.

Answer (score 0):

You can get up to 5 meters accuracy. Within the core location framework there is a property - horizontalAccurracy - that you can read at runtime to get the accuracy for a given moment

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Do you think you can trigger an event based on the location and be almost precise? I mean, imagine that you are in front of the Colosseum in rome and an audio track starts giving you some information.Do you think it is possible? Thanks for the reply

Comment: If the app iss running in the foreground that is an easy task to do. If the app is suspended to the background, you only get significant location changes that are mmuch less precise. But again: if your app is in the foreground, you can get a callback every time the gps coordinate changes

Answer (score 0):

The accuracy is anywhere from 5-25m.